# Передача сигнала в нужный слот, Qt

Tags: qt, сигналы-слоты

Здравствуйте! Есть класс Database, у него есть слот sort:

```
class database {
/*....
public slots:
void sort();
*/
```

Есть диалоговое окно, SortDialogWindow, у которого имеется кнопка QPushButton *sortButton:

```
class SortDialogWindow : public QDialog{
QPushButton *sortButton;
}
```

Хочу добиться следующего: при нажатии на кнопку sortButton вызывается слот sort класса database.
Сделал так:

```
connect(sortButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(sort()));
```

Слот не вызывается, или вызывается, но программа на это никак не реагирует, а как проверить это - я не знаю:(
Как исправить код, чтобы он работал так, как я описал?
Прошу отнестись с пониманием, я только-только начинаю изучать Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то проблема в том, что ваша кнопна находится в классе `SortDialogWindow`, а вам нужно вызвать слот в классе `database`.
Слово `this` в вашем `connect(*, *, this, *);` означает, что при сигнале `clicked()` вызывается слот для этого же класса, т.е. `SortDialogWindow::sort()`. А вам нужно связать данный сигнал с экземпляром класса `database`.
Я предлагаю сделать так:
В классе `SortDialogWindow` создайте сигнал `sortButtonClicked()` и свяжите его с сигналом `clicked()` (`connect(sortButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SIGNAL(sortButtonClicked()));`. Таким образом, при нажатии на кнопку из вашего диалога будет посылаться сигнал. 
После этого, там, где у вас есть экземпляры классов `database` и `SortDialogWindow` свяжите сигнал `sortButtonClicked()` с слотом `sort()`

```
database* _database = new database;  
SortDialogWindow* dialog = new SortDialogWindow;  
connect(dialog, SIGNAL(sortButtonClicked()), _database, SLOT(sort()));
```

Comment: А если у меня окно SortDialogWindow объявляется и открывается методом внутри метода `MainWindow`? Экземпляр класса `database` тоже содержится в `MainWindow`.

        `void MainWindow::sort_click()
{

    SortDialogWindow *log = new SortDialogWindow(0);
    /*...*/
}`


А объект класса `database` объявленен так:

    `data = new database();`

Comment: Сделайте коннект во время создания экземпляра диалога. Объект класса `database` у вас, скорее всего, является полем `MainWindow`. Тогда проблем никаких не возникнет и синтаксис коннекта будет в точности как в ответе

Comment: Объявление диалога и попытка связать:
        `void MainWindow::sort_click()
  {
    SortDialogWindow *log = new SortDialogWindow(0);
    log->exec();
    connect(log, SIGNAL(diagonalClick()), data, SIGNAL(sortDiagonal()));
}`

Ошибка: C:\Users\Arthur\Desktop\kyrsach\MainWindow.cpp:160: ошибка: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(SortDialogWindow*&, const char*, database*&, const char*)'
     connect(log, SIGNAL(diagonalClick()), data, SIGNAL(sortDiagonal()));
                                                                       ^

Comment: @Justskip Прикрепите пожалуйста к вопросу листинги реализации `MainWindwow.h` и данной функции

Comment: @Justskip для начала, зачем вы коннектите сигнал `diagonalClick()` с сигналом `sortDiagonal()`? Вам же нужно было вызвать слот. А это предупреждение означает, что в `database.h` не объявлен сигнал `sortDiagonal()`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!) Разобрался.